# How to get the same look of table when generating pdf from jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter, nbconvert

I have a jupyter notebook python based where I have dataframe output shown- it is 5 columns size. It looks fine in notebook but when I generate pdf using nbconvert command it is being split and only two columns are shown at once

I use custom template, I have an idea to change a bit the size of font in table or wrap the text in column but I cannot find how to address this sort of problem in it.
I tried the PrettyTable class from http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook It looks better however it get cut off one column when the text in previous is longer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally managed it with rather workaround than final solution,I used PrettyTable from Julius Schulz (http://blog.juliusschulz.de/blog/ultimate-ipython-notebook) and in the template I lowered the size of font in tables for whole document by using this:

```
((* block docclass *))
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,prb]{article}

\usepackage{placeins,booktabs,array,tabularx,xparse,authblk}

\AtBeginDocument{
\let\oldtabular\tabular 
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\tiny\oldtabular}
}

((* endblock docclass *))
```

However I think it should be rather done by wrapping-for this I didn't find the solution.